# file_exists using file on different drive

Tags: php, file-exists

Can anyon eplease tell me how I can use this function for a file on a different drive? The code below does not find the file.

```
 $loaded_php = "C:/Program Files(x86)/PHP/v5.3/php.ini";  
  if(file_exists($loaded_php)) 
  {
    $phpini= file_get_contents($loaded_php);
  } else {
    $phpini= "nothing";
  }
```

Comment: Are you using only Windows? Then have a look at "Windows path of remote file". Nevertheless, why are you trying this, it is very ugly :-) You should install a small service on the remote machine that you can use to query for a particular file. Are you interested in the "php.ini" or an arbitrary file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it just Windows, Do you know how I can get the code to work? Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, its on a different drive on my server. Can anyone please tell me how I can state a drive letter in the path? Many thanks

Comment: @MattHarris - There's nothing special about drive letters in PHP and your code is fine because PHP allows `/` as directory separator on Windows. I suggest you copy the file path from Windows explorer, paste it below your code and check for differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to Marc's answer, I recommend to use

```
$loaded_php = 'C:\PROGRA~2\PHP\v5.3\php.ini';
$phpini = file_exists($loaded_php) ? file_get_contents($loaded_php) : 'nothing';
```

Comment: The cons are obvious. What are the pros?

Comment: Call me blind, but what *obvious* cons are you talking about? I always prefer to use `PROGRA~2` over `Program Files (x86)` since it is a) less to type, b) I can not miss any spaces and c) it doesn't require me to escape the path on the command line.

Comment: Well... The most obvious are: 1) The 8+3 compatible path cannot be obtained from Windows explorer, command prompt auto-complete or PHP regular file system functions, it requires running `dir /x` 2) There's no way to say where it points to, you need to actually open it. *(Use whatever you're comfortable with, I was just curious because I had always thought it was just a backwards-compatible hack for legacy 16-bit programs.)*

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I just checked back. Path arguments should **always** avoid spaces in PHP (regardless of single or double quotes are used to wrap the string). Example: This won't work: `<?php system('C:\Program Files (x86)\php\php.exe -v 2>&1', $o); echo $o; ?>`. This will work: `<?php system('C:\Progra~2\php\php.exe -v 2>&1', $o); echo $o; ?>`. Another one: This won't work: `FcgidWrapper "c:/program files (x86)/php/php-cgi.exe" .php` But this will: 
`FcgidWrapper "c:/progra~2/php/php-cgi.exe" .php`.

Comment: Yes, if you feed `system()` with an invalid command, PHP won't fix it for you. It isn't surprising.

Comment: Whether SFNs are meant as a *backwards-compatible hack for legacy 16-bit programs* or not, I'll leave it up to the pros. But from my almost 10 years of experience in hacking php applications in windows environments, I can tell you that I never had issues resolving the PROGRA~x paths whereas I had a couple of issues with spaces in paths braking functionality.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Invalid command? Check the formatted code here http://pastebin.com/p0cG9ywB, run it on a windows machine and you will see that the only thing that is breaking the functionality is the space in path.

Comment: Take your own command, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe remount 2>&1`, and run it from a Windows command prompt. It isn't a PHP problem at all. You seem to have taken this personally—as I said, you have the choice to use short paths and you've provided 3 valid reasons. There's no need to justify your choice claiming that there's no other way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Typo:

```
 $loaded_php = "C:/Program Files(x86)/PHP/v5.3/php.ini";  
                                ^---missing space
```

It's `Program Files[SPACE](x86)`

Comment: Thanks very much again guys, still no joy. Tried C:\PROGRA~2\PHP\v5.3\php.ini,  file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/v5.3/php.ini and C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/v5.3/php.ini - non of them work......any other ideas?